# Get the running balance of several tables with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several tables with the same structure. It has different values for the price. I want to get the running balance of the price column. So I want to get the sum and print each iteration in the running balance column. For example. In the Price column I have 400, 425 and 350 so in the running balance column, I should have 400, 825, 1175. Currently, I'm only getting the sum.

Here is my html

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="60%">Item</th>
      <th width="20%">Price</th>
      <th width="20%">Running Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Bacon</td>
      <td class="price">1300</td>
      <td class="runningBal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pancakes</td>
      <td class="price">300</td>
       <td class="runningBal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total:</b></td>
      <td class="total"><b>$</b></td>
       <td class="totalBal"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="60%">Item</th>
      <th width="20%">Price</th>
      <th width="20%">Running Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fries</td>
      <td class="price">400</td>
      <td class="runningBal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nuggets</td>
      <td class="price">425</td>
      <td class="runningBal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ice Cream</td>
      <td class="price">350</td>
      <td class="runningBal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total:</b></td>
      <td class="total"><b>$</b></td>
      <td class="totalBal"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

here is my javascript

```
$('.runningBal').each(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(this).parents('table').find('.price').each(function() {
    var floted = parseFloat($(this).text());
    if (!isNaN(floted)) sum += floted;

    $('.runningBal').html(sum);
  })

  //$(this).html(sum);
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xukt3vkz/)

Comment: how do you generate these table. ? You should calculate running balance and place it during table rendering..

Comment: I generate the tables with a foreach with PHP but I am only showing a less complicated version here

Comment: Then as you encounter price, you should store it in a variable and echo it at running balance column. Simply, the logic is best placed at php side if you are not doing any changes to the price on clientside.

Comment: I'm using laravel blade though. I just thought it would be easier to use jquery.

Comment: @Panther is right - should be processed server-side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well people in the comments are right to say that if the product prices are constant, you should render it server-side while you loop.

Anyway, this will do the job :

```js
$("table").each(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(this).find(".runningBal").each(function() {
   sum += +$(this).prev(".price").text();
    $(this).text(sum);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="60%">Item</th>
      <th width="20%">Price</th>
      <th width="20%">Running Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Bacon</td>
      <td class="price">1300</td>
      <td class="runningBal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pancakes</td>
      <td class="price">300</td>
       <td class="runningBal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total:</b></td>
      <td class="total"><b>$</b></td>
       <td class="totalBal"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="60%">Item</th>
      <th width="20%">Price</th>
      <th width="20%">Running Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fries</td>
      <td class="price">400</td>
      <td class="runningBal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nuggets</td>
      <td class="price">425</td>
      <td class="runningBal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ice Cream</td>
      <td class="price">350</td>
      <td class="runningBal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total:</b></td>
      <td class="total"><b>$</b></td>
      <td class="totalBal"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I know they're right but it's sort of complicated. That's why I think it would be easier to just use jquery. Thanks again